# Get DNS script has missing output in report

Tags: powershell

```
<# 
Gets the various dns record type for a domain or use -RecordType all for all and -Report to file output.
Use like .\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -Name Facebook -RecordType all or .\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -name facebook -RecordType MX
#>
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
        HelpMessage = "Specifies the domain.")]
    [string]$Name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False,
        HelpMessage = "Which Record.")]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'MX', 'TXT', 'All')]
    [string]$RecordType = 'txt',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        HelpMessage = "DNS Server to use.")]
    [string]$Server = '8.8.8.8',
  
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        HelpMessage = "Make a csv report in c:\Reports")]
    [Switch]$Report
)

IF ($Name -notlike "*.*") {
    $Name = $Name + '.com'
}

If ($Report) {
    $filename = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments") + '\' + $($RecordType) + '-' + ($Name.Split('.')[0]) + '.csv'
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'txt' -or $RecordType -eq 'All') {
    $TXTRecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type txt -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
            name    = $_.name
            type    = $_.Type
            ttl     = $_.ttl
            section = $_.Section
            strings = ($_.strings | Out-String).trim()
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'txt') {
        $TXTRecord
        If ($Report) {
            $TXTRecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
        }
        $TXTRecord
        Return write-host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'mx' -or $RecordType -eq 'All' ) {
    $MXRecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type mx -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'MX') {
        If ($Report) {
            $MXRecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
        }
        $MXRecord
        Return  Write-Host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'a' -or $RecordType -eq 'All' ) {
    $ARecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type A -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name       = $_.name
            Type       = $_.type
            TTL        = $_.ttl
            Section    = $_.section
            IP4Address = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'a') {
        If ($Report) {
            $ARecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
        }
        $ARecord
        Return write-host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($Report) {
    $TXTRecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
    $MXRecord | Select-Object name, Type, ttyl, section, NameExchange | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
    $ARecord | Select-Object name, Type, ttyl, section, IP4Address | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
}
$TXTRecord
$MXRecord
$ARecord 
Return Write-Host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
```

Running `.\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -Name Facebook -RecordType all -Report`

Example report Output file is like the following and the host blast is ugly as well.

```
"name","type","ttl","section","strings"
"Facebook.com","TXT","3600","Answer","String"
"Facebook.com","TXT","3600","Answer","String"
"FaceBook.com","MX","21001","Answer",
"FaceBook.com","MX","21001","Answer",
"FaceBook.com","A","20","Answer",
```

Mx is missing `NameExchange`

A record is missing `IP4Address`

Ideas on how to make the report output include the missing items and bonus how to make the host output more readable ?

The problem is when I try to combine the output variables at the end and then export to file. I am just not sure how to correct it.

Comment: I had this on code review but I think it belongs here because there is a problem in the code.

Comment: Once you export the first object to the csv, you cant add any more columns, that's why your IP addresses are missing. You can make sure all fields are in all export objects, or prepolulate the csv headers or export a "dummy" object to it first so that all the columsn you need are there before you start exporting objects with data.

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to do what you;re doing, if nobody else posts, I'll take a look and add an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I am interested in seeing the better way if you get a chance @Scepticalist. I will look at making the dummy object first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did. If someone has a better answer please let me know.

Running `.\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -Name Facebook -RecordType all -Report`

The key lines are as follows.

```
$final = $TXTRecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }
    $final += $MXRecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }
    $final += $ARecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }

    $final | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Full code below

```
<# 
Gets the various dns record type for a domain or use -RecordType all for all and -Report to file output.
Use like .\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -Name Facebook -RecordType all or .\get-dnsrecords.ps1 -name facebook -RecordType MX
#>
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
        HelpMessage = "Specifies the domain.")]
    [string]$Name,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $False,
        HelpMessage = "Which Record.")]
    [ValidateSet('A', 'MX', 'TXT', 'All')]
    [string]$RecordType = 'all',

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        HelpMessage = "DNS Server to use.")]
    [string]$Server = '8.8.8.8',
  
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
        HelpMessage = "Make a csv report in c:\Reports")]
    [Switch]$Report
)

IF ($Name -notlike "*.*") {
    $Name = $Name + '.com'
}

If ($Report) {
    $filename = [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments") + '\' + $($RecordType) + '-' + ($Name.Split('.')[0]) + '.csv'
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'txt' -or $RecordType -eq 'All') {
    $TXTRecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type txt -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
            name    = $_.name
            type    = $_.Type
            ttl     = $_.ttl
            section = $_.Section
            strings = ($_.strings | Out-String).trim()
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'txt') {
        $TXTRecord
        If ($Report) {
            $TXTRecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ','
        }
        $TXTRecord
        Return write-host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'mx' -or $RecordType -eq 'All' ) {
    $MXRecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type mx -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'MX') {
        If ($Report) {
            $MXRecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
        }
        $MXRecord
        Return  Write-Host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($RecordType -eq 'a' -or $RecordType -eq 'All' ) {
    $ARecord = Resolve-DnsName $Name -Type A -Server $Server -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name       = $_.name
            Type       = $_.type
            TTL        = $_.ttl
            Section    = $_.section
            IP4Address = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }

    If ($RecordType -eq 'a') {
        If ($Report) {
            $ARecord | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
        }
        $ARecord
        Return write-host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
    }
}

If ($Report) {
    $final = $TXTRecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }
    $final += $MXRecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }
    $final += $ARecord | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name         = $_.name
            Type         = $_.type
            TTL          = $_.ttl
            Section      = $_.section
            strings      = $_.strings
            NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
            IP4Address   = $_.IP4Address
        }
    }

    $final | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation

}
$TXTRecord
$MXRecord
$ARecord 
Return Write-Host $filename -ForegroundColor blue
```